# how to create a model whenever a user is added to specific group in django

Tags: django, python-3.x

in django User and i have 2 groups, i want whenever i create a user, create a corresponding profile for it (depending on which group it belongs to) how should i manage it?

i have used this method:

```
def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created'] :
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

But it creates userprofile whenever i create a user.
How can I have conditions to check which group it belongs too and then have create corresponding profile for it

In my registration process i made sure they have a group and it cant be changed

```
    if 'signup_provider_btn' in request.POST:
        providers = Group.objects.get(name='providers')
        providers.user_set.add(user)
    elif 'signup_user_btn' in request.POST:
        users = Group.objects.get(name='users')
        users.user_set.add(user)
```

creating a user and assigning it to a group:

```
    user = User()
    username = request.POST.get('username', '')
    user.username = username
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')
    user.set_password(password)
    # users.name = request.POST.get("")
    # users.image = request.POST.get("phone")
    user.save()
    if 'signup_provider_btn' in request.POST:
        providers = Group.objects.get(name='providers')
        providers.user_set.add(user)
    elif 'signup_user_btn' in request.POST:
        users = Group.objects.get(name='users')
        users.user_set.add(user)
```

Comment: What are you going to do if someone changes the user's group ? What if the user is created with more than one group ? Or with no group at all ? Also, the user record is created before it's added to any group, so you won't never get this information at this stage (I mean, in a post_save handler called with `created=True`).

Comment: I edited my question, u can see they have group and is just one of them and there is no way to change it

Comment: the fact you're doing this in your registration process doesn't garantee a user will have a group and a single one - a user can be created outside your registration process -  nor that there's no way it's group(s) won't ever change (this can be done in the admin or by just any part of the code). And from experience, I can _garantee_ you will have to deal with those cases at one point or another (unless your project is abandonned before being ever used at least).

Comment: As a side note: the above excerpt of your "registration process" code contains the very obious answer to your question - create the profile at this point, which is where you _do_ have all the relevant informations ;-)

Comment: yeah i figured it out after i asked it but i wanted to make use of signal and sender thank you by the way

Comment: Also - I just noticed your "user creation" code - do yoursef a favour and use django forms for user input validation - specially when they are already provided (in this case by the django.contrib.auth app).

Comment: I have some javascript functions that they are connected by input id in my html, that's why i cant use django form

Comment: What make you think that there's any issue using js with django form ??? Of course you can use both - I did on dozen projects FWIW. HTML rendering can be customised at will, and it's only an accessory part of django forms actually - the most important part is validation / type conversion etc.

Comment: how am i gonna give an  id to django form in html so I can link proper js function to it??

Comment: The forms rendering API is rather extensively documented, and you can of course check the generated markup by yourself - not to mention the numerous examples you can find in various tutorials, blogs articles and third-part apps source code...  But if even after seriously researching the topic (instead of assuming that "you can't") you still have issues making it work, feel free to post this as a real question here (with real-life - eventually dumbed-down - example code etc, cf https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).